# PHP File Upload is not working in jquery ajax form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax form to display form dynamically in which it contains the file upload option. I'm getting the post values of every text values but the File array is empty. 
I have executed `print_r($_POST)` and `print_r($_FILES)` to see the post data, the $_FILES Array is showing null value.

Here is the form I'm using.

```
<form class="form-3 form-horizontal ajxfrm" id="step-three" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo $html->addLink(array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'step_three_ajax')); ?>" method="post">
<div id="calendar">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label"><label class="control-label">Name</label></div>
            <div class="controls"><input id="name" type="text" name="name" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">Email</div>
            <div class="controls"><input id="email" type="text" name="email" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">Contact</div>
            <div class="controls"><input id="contact" type="text" name="contact" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">Files<br/><span style="font-size:10px; font-style:italic">(Optional)</span></div>
            <div class="controls">
                <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" /><br/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="position:relative">
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="control-label">Your Message</div>
            <div class="controls"><textarea id="message" rows="3" name="message"></textarea></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="submit">       
    <input type="hidden" name="post" value="1"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next"/> 
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the ajax call

```
$('.ajxfrm').live('submit',function(){
    var thisObj = this;
    var submit = true;
    if('step-two'==$(thisObj).attr('id')){
        submit = stepTwo();
    }else if('step-three'==$(thisObj).attr('id')){
        submit = stepThree();
    }           
    if(submit){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $(thisObj).serialize(),
            url: $(thisObj).attr('action'),
            beforeSend: function(){
                showOverLayer();
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(thisObj).parent("#content").empty().html(data).hide().fadeIn(function(){
                    setBlocks();
                    setLiClick();
                    hideOverLayer();
                });
                changeCalNaviHref();
            }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here im calling the upload function using $booker->uploadfiles(); in controller
here is the controller method function

```
public function step_three(){
    //save booking
    if(isset($_POST['post'])){
        $booker = new Booker();     
        //create booker
        $_SESSION['userdat']['name']=$_POST['name'];
        $_SESSION['userdat']['email']=$_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['userdat']['contact']=$_POST['contact'];
        $_SESSION['userdat']['message']=$_POST['message'];

        if($booker->setsessions($_SESSION['userdat']))
        {
            $booker->uploadfiles();
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'homes','action'=>'step_four'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->setFlashMsg('Please Provide Valid Information','message-box ok');
        }
    }
}
```

here is the model function uploadfiles()

```
public function uploadfiles()
    {
    if(isset($_FILES['fileupload']))
    {
        $errors= array();
        foreach($_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name )
        {
            print_r($_FILES);
            exit;
            $file_name = $key.$_FILES['fileupload']['name'][$key];
            $file_size =$_FILES['fileupload']['size'][$key];
            $file_tmp =$_FILES['fileupload']['tmp_name'][$key];
            $file_type=$_FILES['fileupload']['type'][$key]; 
            if($file_size > 2097152)
            {
                $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
            }   
            $upload_dir = ROOT;
            $desired_dir="/uploads/";
            if(empty($errors)==true)
            {
                if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false)
                {
                    mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700); // Create directory if it does not exist
                }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false)
            {
                //$file_path=$upload_dir."$desired_dir/".$file_name;
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$upload_dir."$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }
            else
            {                                           // rename the file if another one exist
                $file_path=$upload_dir."$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                rename($file_tmp,$file_path) ;              
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error))
    {
            //echo "Success"; exit;
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Your actual `uploading` function perhaps? `move_uploaded_file` ;-) and the fact that your Ajax has no URL set to your PHP uploading code. **Q:** Where did you get those codes from? I doubt you're showing us everything here.

Comment: i updated the question -Fred

Comment: Thank you Kiran. Now, can you explain this line for me? `$upload_dir = ROOT;` - I think this is proprietary to CodeIgniter, am I right?

Comment: ROOT is nothing but the root directory.. I have defined as a global variable.

Comment: You mentioned `$_FILES Array`. Are you allowing for multiple uploads?

Comment: first i was trying with multiple files but then i switched to single file upload to test the program..if i access this 3rd page directly and if i upload one file then the files are uploading but when i dynamically show the form using ajax then if it wont upload the file, it doest works –

Comment: Usually and in Pure PHP, when uploading multiple files, they are set in an array, where the name in the form for example yours  `name="fileupload"` would have added brackets as such `name="fileupload[]"`. That's why I asked about the "array".

Comment: Fred:- i have added the fileupload[] before to use as multiple file uploads... i think its because of enctype multipart/form-data, the ajax call is not creating the enctype attribute

Comment: Hm, not sure about the `enctype` being at fault, but won't leave it out of the equation. I'm starting to question `if(isset($_POST['post'])){`. I see it's associated with `<input type="hidden" name="post" value="1"/>`. I've seen another case a few days ago, where if it was a "hidden" value, the upload wouldn't work. Why don't you try `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` just to "test" it out and name your `<input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next"/> ` to `<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next"/>`

Comment: k wait i'll give a try

Comment: OOoohhhhhhhh **Wait a minute**, I just noticed something. You're using **"sessions"**. `session_start();` is missing from your "posted" code. If you don't have it in there, then that must be on TOP of every `.php` file.

Comment: i have started the session at top in controller.. thats not the issue

Comment: Darn it, I was sure that was it. And my other suggestion didn't work, I take it.?

Comment: And adding a `name` to `<input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next"/>` as in `<input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn green" value="Next"/>` didn't work neither?

Comment: no buddy... No luck again

Comment: I am completely **"baffled"**. Nothing in your `.htaccess` that would play tricks on you neither? I've seen that happen before also.

Comment: me completely baffled from 2 days

Comment: What about in your `foreach...`. I noticed `print_r($_FILES); exit;` - Doesn't `exit;` STOP execution?

Comment: ya its just to echo the uploaded files.. it shows empty array when i upload the file... I Kept for testing purpose

Comment: Ok. Another thing `$desired_dir="/uploads/";` You have a forward slash at the end. And in `$file_path=$upload_dir."$desired_dir/"` you also have another forward slash. I doubt it's the problem, but do you think otherwise? And in a few other areas also.

Comment: Try removing the slash at the end of `/uploads/` to read as `/uploads` maybe?

Comment: Fred my friend, thats my root upload folder, its working fine if i access the 3rd step page directly.. the problem is the form wizrd, it has 4 steps, one form in each page, if i click next in one page then the next form is loaded using the ajax call which i shown above

Comment: So you think the problem is inside your `uploadfiles()` class model or in `step_three()`?

Comment: no... the problem is with ajax call. the uploadfiles() is working fine when i access the page directly.. i think its due to enctype

Comment: if u get any solution the pls PM me at kirant043@gmail.com... And Ha Special thanks for putting your efforts... I'll be waiting ur reply

Comment: You have `'action'=>'step_three_ajax'` in your `action`, yet you have `else if('step-three'==$(thisObj).attr('id')){` and `function step_three(){`. Something doesn't seem to match here, nor do I see another call to `step_three_ajax`.

Comment: You're welcome Kiran. Yet, did you have a look at my comment, just above this one?

Comment: step_three() functions is for validation of input fields.. it returns true after all inputs have correct values

Comment: But you have the action set as `'action'=>'step_three_ajax'`, isn't that supposed to be `'action'=>'step_three'`?

Comment: you see here else if('step-three'==$(thisObj).attr('id')){
            submit = stepThree(); this is where the validations goes and returns true and it goes step_three_ajax

Comment: You have `'action'=>'step_three'` and `if('step-three'`. Notice the **"dash"** (-) in `step-three` in your `if...` instead of an **underscore** ( _ ) in your `action'=>...`?

Comment: @MarkScultheiss, I don't think this is a duplicate. OP mentioned he has success when accessing the upload page directly. It is only a problem when loading forms via ajax...

Comment: @jasonnathan u r right... I found that file upload wont works in ajax

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
$('.ajxfrm').live('submit',function(){
        var thisObj = $(this),
            submit = true;

        if('step-two'== thisObj.attr('id')){
            submit = stepTwo();
        }else if('step-three'== thisObj.attr('id')){
            submit = stepThree();
        }
        if(submit){
            $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              data: thisObj.serialize(),
              url: thisObj.attr('action'),
              beforeSend: function(){
                 showOverLayer();
              },
              success: function(data){
                 thisObj.parent("#content").empty().html(data).hide().fadeIn(function(){
                     setBlocks();
                     setLiClick();
                     hideOverLayer();
                 });
                 changeCalNaviHref();
              }
            });
        }
    return false;
});
```

Can you show me one console.log(data) on the success method?

Thanks

Comment: Sorry buddy... it didnt worked... if i access this 3rd page directly and if i upload one file then the files are uploading but when i dynamically show the form using ajax then if it wont upload the file, it doest works

Comment: I'm not developing here, but...when you return false in a submit form, don't you blocking to send?

Comment: @RafaelGomes, `return false` just prevents the default submit action of the form. These days though, we use `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Thanks @jasonnathan, you're completely right! I got confused for a minute. :)

Answer (score 0):

Two total long shots here:

1) You mentioned that your sessioning code is "up top".  Are you using something like `session_regenerate_id` there?  That will mess with parallel uploads.

or

2) Take a look at whether your session file is locked when other sessions are coming in.  google an article or two on `session_write_close()`.

But its more likely to be #1.

Comment: no i'm not using sessions_regenerate_id here... IF i echo all the sessions then its showing the correct values

Comment: If its getting lost in ajax, have you viewed the interaction with either Fiddler or Firebug? See what's posted over to the server and if its different with one file versus multiple files.

Comment: No i didnt checked... Actually I dnt know how to use the Fiddler

Comment: I find Firebug slightly easier to use, but its a Firefox add in. If you're using something else, use Fiddler. In Firebug, under Net, check the POST to see what is being sent over with one and multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send files using 'old' AJAX (not this way).

If you want to send files, take a look at XMLHttpRequest2. Pretty good tutorial is here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/